# Searching for Easy Way in SAS to Vertically Stack Different Variable Names to One

Tags: sas, stack, output, rename

Faced with situation where vendor had different varname counts when one variable will actually suffice. Imagine the following very simplified version of my SAS code. Here there are five variables of interest but I am OUTPUTing it to 2 tables/dataframes that may be stacked once I RENAME the key variables in each file.

```
data
ABA ADDI;
set zach.COMMERCIAL_A12;
keep 
PRODUCT_DESC
ABA_NUMERCNT
ADD_INITIATION_NUMERCNT;
if ABA_DENOMCNT = 1 then output ABA;
if ADD_INITIATION_DENOMCNT = 1 then output ADDI;
run;
```

Right now the program creates the two new OUTPUT files = ABA and ADDI. Each of the files has the same three variables from my KEEP. Later on I will stack them. So for ABA I wish to keep only PRODUCT_DESC & ABA_NUMERCNT and for ADDI I wish to keep PRODUCT_DESC & ADD_INITIATION_NUMERCNT. But before stacking them I would like to sort of automate it so that ABA_NUMERCNT becomes VarTemp and ADD_INITIATION_NUMERCNT again becomes VarTemp before they are stacked.

Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: It would help to include a fraction of the data you have and the data you want.

Comment: Added a picture - hopefully easy to follow. I highlighted in Yellow the table names.

Comment: You went to the trouble of typing  text into excel and taking a photograph of it.  It would have been easier and more helpful to just type the text directly into the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use dataset options on your output datasets.  It is a little hard to follow the details of your question but it looks like you want something like:

```
data
  ABA (rename=(ABA_DENOMCNT=newvar ) drop=ADD_INITIATION_DENOMCNT  )
  ADDI (rename=(ADD_INITIATION_DENOMCNT=newvar) drop=ABA_DENOMCNT )
;
  set zach.COMMERCIAL_A12;
  keep PRODUCT_DESC ABA_NUMERCNT ADD_INITIATION_NUMERCNT;
  if ABA_DENOMCNT = 1 then output ABA;
  if ADD_INITIATION_DENOMCNT = 1 then output ADDI;
run;
```